# Embedded database sqlite or SQL Server CE for desktop application

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

I am writing a small desktop application that will use its own local embedded database. No need to client/server db.

I have read about SQL Server CE and SqLite, both free of course and have its pros/cons.

I'm wondering for a Visual Studio project, C#. What is the major differences between them and what would be easier to work with, any recommendations? I have googled this and all I have found was old outdated information.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Comment: read that.. i'm looking for more a personal experience

Comment: Feel free to email me!